# How to add html in calculated column of a list in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column

I need to create a calculated column based on a hyperlink.

The link will open the form in edit mode + id.

I'm not familiar with JS, how can this be completed?

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that using a calculated column in SharePoint Online any more ([this was disabled June 2017](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4032106/handling-html-markup-in-sharepoint-calculated-fields)).

The way to do this will be using a [Field Customizer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/building-simple-field-customizer) (if modern) or [JSLink](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/37203.sharepoint-online-customize-list-view-web-part-using-jslink.aspx) (if classic), but both require JS development.

If all you want it to add an Edit link to a classic view, then that's available as an OOTB "Column", just edit your view and select the "column" Edit (Link to edit item)":
[image]
This will show as an icon in the view (but only in classic):
[image]

Comment: do you have  an example of how this link can be created? maybe the JS link?

Comment: @DanielleMareeSutton Added info about OOTB Edit "column"

Answer (score 1):

**Method in classic experience:** Use JSOM to generate the path and overwrite a column value.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function displayLayover(url) {
var options = SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions();
options.url = url;
SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options); 
 }

(function () {
    var overrideNameField = {}; 
    overrideNameField.Templates = {};
    // This action will edit the “Title” field. You can change the “Title” to another field.
    overrideNameField.Templates.Fields = {
        //"LinkTitle" is the internal name of the "Title" field in the list
        "LinkTitle": { "View": overrideNameFieldTemplate }        
    };    
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideNameField);
})();

function overrideNameFieldTemplate(ctx) { 
    var itemID = ctx.CurrentItem.ID;
//You can set a field value as you want.
var content = "edit properties";
    //Or, get the item column value, such as Title
//var content = ctx.CurrentItem["Title"];
    // here the url should be of your list
var url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl +"/Lists/<list>/Item/EditForm.aspx?ID="+ itemId;
    return "<a href='" + url+ "'>" + content + "</a>"; 
}
</script>
```